# fa icons pushing the elements away

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-awesome, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a navigation menu with some tabs. However, the tabs under the tabs with "fa icons" are kinda taking too much space and the other elements are shifted to the right or below (if there was a third line).

How can I avoid this pushing?

It looks like this:
[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/63peh71b/1/

```css
.slider {
    position: fixed;
    top: 168px;
    background-color: white;
    left: 48px;
    right: 48px;
    z-index: 3;
    padding-top: 6px;
}

.nav-tabs {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
}

.nav {
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

ol, ul {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul, menu, dir {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: disc;
    -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
    -webkit-padding-start: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/css/tether.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs slider">
<li id="id1" class=""><a href="javascript:;"><i class="fa fa-warning" style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0);"></i> Tab1</a></li>
<li id="id2"><a href="javascript:;"><i class="fa fa-warning" style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0);"></i> Tab2</a></li>
<li id="id3"><a href="javascript:;"><i class="fa fa-warning" style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0);"></i> Tab 3</a></li>
<li id="id4"><a href="javascript:;"><i class="fa fa-warning" style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0);"></i> Tab 4</a></li>
<li id="id5"><a href="javascript:;"><i class="fa fa-warning" style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0);"></i> Tab 5</a></li>
<li id="id6"><a href="javascript:;">Tab 6</a></li>
<li id="id7"><a href="javascript:;">Tab 7</a></li>
<li id="id8"><a href="javascript:;">Tab 8</a></li>
<li id="id9"><a href="javascript:;">adsadsadsad Tab 9</a></li>
<li id="id10" class="active"><a href="javascript:;">Tab 10</a></li>
<li id="id11"><a href="javascript:;">Tab 11</a></li>
<li id="id12"><a href="javascript:;">Tab 12</a></li>
<li id="id13"><a href="javascript:;">Tab 13</a></li>
<li id="id14"><a href="javascript:;">Tab14</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you include relevant external links in your snippet? It's not clear what the issue is from what you've posted, thanks

Comment: @ovokuro I have edited the question

Comment: if there is so much tab then it is obviously, pushing tabs to next line.`fa` is not pushing tab to next line , there is no space at then end then it is automatically push to next line.

Comment: @chiragsatapara check how tab12 doesn't start under tab1...

Comment: @Sammy , it is starting under the tab1 , see this image link https://ibb.co/kgkTkQ

Comment: @chiragsatapara check my attached image...

Comment: @Sammy The tabs are lining up correctly for me in the jsFiddle you posted. Can you check if there are differences in the code you've used? Use the dev tools to help you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
header{
position:relative;
}
#yourNavIconsTab {
li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding:3px;
    float:right;
    color:@brand-primary;
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    top:0px;
  } 
}
```

You might need to adjust the `top` and `right` values.